# Change max length of a URL param

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I need to `GET` a param with a length of 1727 characters, now, I can get only 512. How I can do this with `.htaccess`?

Current `htaccess`:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This may help you [maximum length of HTTP GET request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Answer (score 2):

It's not related to webserver. Proxy servers and browsers have their own url length limitations and likely that's what caused the issue.

Comment: @Gabriel Santos: well, I wanted to say that it's not webserver's issue. Check access logs and see that url is already passed truncated.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, add the follow line to `.htaccess`:

```
php_value suhosin.get.max_value_length 2000
```

Comment: it was because that line is incomplete, the htaccess line should be: `php_value suhosin.get.max_value_length 2048`, omitting the `php_value` is what caused the 500. Having the command blocked (as indeed it was) would not cause the 500